# What does this "As lifts over &" AsRef impl mean?

Tags: rust

On debugging (step-in) this Rust code:

```rust
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    fs::create_dir("my_dir").unwrap();
}
```

I go to an impl I feel hard to understand:

```rust
// rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\src\rust\library\core\src\convert\mod.rs

// As lifts over &
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<T: ?Sized, U: ?Sized> AsRef<U> for &T
where
    T: AsRef<U>,
{
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &U {
        <T as AsRef<U>>::as_ref(*self)
    }
}
```

Which then calls:

```rust
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl AsRef<Path> for str {
    #[inline]
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Path {
        Path::new(self)
    }
}
```

What does this "As lifts over &" impl mean? Why it is needed?

This piece of code:

```rust
<T as AsRef<U>>
```

I've never seen this syntax before. What does it mean?

Seems like there is a lot of implicit conversions like this done by Rust compiler behind our daily Rust code. Is there any way to learn them besides debugging?

Answer (score 2):

I assume `As lifts over &` simply means that if `T` can be taken as a reference to `U`, so does `&T`, because why not?

It also gives some convenience, e.g. if you happened to have a value of type `&&&&&&T`, you won't need to `(******t).as_ref()`, it's just `t.as_ref()`, because by using such implementation, `as_ref` goes through all levels of references up to the `T` object itself and takes it as a reference to `U`.

How can you learn it? Well, the top 3 most popular Rust textbooks have it in some way (not necessarily explicitly explaining you this particular case, but giving you enough knowledge to understand them implicitly. So I advice you to read one (and read it more carefully).

About the `<T as AsRef<U>>`, it is definitely covered in the books. It's needed to [disambiguate calls to functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html#disambiguating-function-calls). For example, if some type implements two different traits, but both traits have the same method `as_ref`, then you'll need to *fully qualify* function of which trait you mean to call, for this you `<T as AsRef<U>>` and it's immediately clear which `as_ref` function you call.

Comment: By learning, I mean, can we ask the compiler to provide more information about the choice of traits in a particular expression, the actual type parameters inferred, etc? Much like debugging macro expansions in C or debugging template expansions in C++. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @brk Never heard about something similar for Rust, because I never needed it. Rust is implemented in a tidy way that it's explicit when you can screw things up and it's conveniently implicit when compiler can infer what you actually meant (e.g. in the same example, when it crawls over all references to cast the real object, not just a reference to it)

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have 2 traits that share an item and a type that implements both. You can use this syntax to specify which implementation to use.

```rust
pub trait Foo {
    const BAZ: usize;
}


pub trait Bar {
    const BAZ: usize;
}

pub fn thing<T: Foo + Bar>() {
    // This wont compile since it doesn't know which BAZ to use
    println!("Unknown: {}", T::BAZ);

    // You can use <a as b>::c to further specify which to use
    println!("As Foo: {}", <T as Foo>::BAZ);
    println!("As Bar: {}", <T as Bar>::BAZ);
}
```

You can read `<A as B>::C` as follows where `C` can be anything inside a trait (constant, function, type, etc.). It can also be used to make your code more verbose. If it is unclear which trait is being used, this can help make your code more explicit.

**"Interpret type `A` as an instance of trait `B` for the purpose of retrieving `C`"**